# Check if form is Opened Winform / Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, runspace

I'm searching how I could check if a winform form is opened with Powershell, like [this response for VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439440/check-if-form-is-opened). I'm working with two runspaces, and I need to start the second, when my form is opened.

My first runspace is for the GUI. When the UI creation is completed, I opened it

```
$CommonHashTable.MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

And then, I'm trying to test if this form is opened (snipet from VB.net) from PowerShell main thread:

```
If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of $CommonHashTable.MainForm).Any Then
 ... startsecondrunspace
```

Comment: What exactly is your question / problem? Do you struggle with 'translating' the last snippet `If Application.OpenForms().OfType ...` to PoSh?

Comment: Yes, I'm searching how to convert in Powershell this sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to test if the form is open might be to

```
if ($CommonHashTable.MainForm.IsHandleCreated) {
    startsecondrunspace
}
```

Application.OpenForms() would be a method on an Application Class rather than the Form class. I am unsure if there is an instance of the Application class to even be able to use that method. If there was, I would imagine it should look something like this:

```
If ($ApplicationObject.OpenForms().OfType(Of $CommonHashTable.MainForm).Any) {
    startsecondrunspace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much, I have created this function :

```
do {
    RecordToLog -Message "Waiting..."
    start-sleep -m 100
} until ($CommonHashTable.MainForm.IsHandleCreated)
startsecondrunspace
```

It's working.