# Button clicked proceed to mew windows form event (Once only)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Good day developers,

I just want to ask if it is possible, once I clicked a button, it appearing the new windows form only once, because as of now it works for me but when I clicked a button many times it appear the windows form multiple times. Is that possible? (Sorry for my english :D)

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles Button.ItemClick
        Dim newForm As New MyForm
        newForm.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Before you open anew form check with openforms if it is already open

Comment: @nbk I need to open that because its a part of the system.

Comment: And? you check before hand of your form is open with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.openforms?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 and if not start a new one else set the focues on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439568/14171304

Comment: Possible that maybe newForm.ShowDialog() might also be what you're needing.  That will allow you to stop focus going back to the original calling form until newForm is closed